# C# Selenium - write an own click() method

Tags: c#, selenium, methods, click

i wanna write an own click() method and override it with different types. My problem is that i don´t know the datatypes of:

- id
- xpath
- name
- value

Normally i write:
    `driver.FindElement(By.Id("GUI-id").Click();`

And i want a method like this: 
    `click("GUI-id");`

Who can help me...?

Comment: Well, you still need to specify type of selector, because without it Selenium won't know how to find it. You can make assumption that by default it's id and treat this `GUI-id` as id selector, but for other cases you still need to specify them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`By.something` is a `By` object. You can send it to the method like this

```
public void Click(By by)
{
    driver.FindElement(by).Click();
}
```

And call it like this

```
Click(By.Id("GUI-id")); 
Click(By.Name("GUI-name"));
// etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are a possibility to cut short!? The method "click()" should decide which parameter was set?

Comment: like `click("GUI.id");` and `click("GUI-name")`

Comment: @splatterjoe you can do `public void Click(string id)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.id(id)).Click();
}` but it will be limited to `Id` selectors. In my answer you can send all the selectors.

Comment: every parameter is a String... thats the problem... okay, so i am using your method from the first answer... thank you and have a nice day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do something like

```
public void Click(string something)
{
    if(driver.FindElement(By.Id(something)).Count > 0)
       driver.FindElement(By.Id(something)).Click();
    else if (driver.FindElement(By.Name(something)).Count > 0)
       driver.FindElement(By.Name(something)).Click();
//and so on...
}
```

call

```
Click("GUI-id");
```

**BUT ITS NOT EFFECTIVE AT ALL!**

Comment: you can do the main recognize tags in the method: Id, ClassName, Name.

Comment: Okay. I understand the problem with the same strings -> solution-> 2nd parameter for id/name etc  ... There are other "problems" that must be observed?

Comment: just will take more time that's all

Answer (score 0):

C# offers extension methods for this purpose:

```
public static class MyExtensionMethodsOrWhateverNameYouLike
{
    public static void Click(this IWebElement element)
    {
        element.Click();
    }
}
```

Note the `this` keyword in the definition of the `Click()` method. This will override the default `IWebElement.Click()` and call your custom method instead.

Or you can overload the method with additional params:

```
public static class MyExtensionMethodsOrWhateverNameYouLike
{
    public static void Click(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        //driver.DoSomething();
        element.Click();
    }
}
```

In this case, you can call it like this:

```
IWebDriver driver;
IWebElement element;
...
element.Click(driver);
```